# Auto comment alignment in VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Ever since I started using VS2017 for my C# coding, auto-formatting aligns all comments at the end of the line to the same column, and I can't seem to find an option to turn this off. In theory it would be a good feature, but it bothers me that code like this:

```
DoSomething(); // comment
// TODO: something
```

is auto-formatted to

```
DoSomething(); // comment
               // TODO: something
```

Is there *some way* to turn that off?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the default settings - do you have any addons installed? At what point does it autoformat and indent the comment? When you press ENTER at the end of the comment?

Comment: It does it whenever I make VS auto-format, and it's been doing it from the start, before I installed any addons =/ Though it's certainly weird it isn't happening on your installation.